# Quantile aggregation for string fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, percentile, quantile

I have a **string** field in an elasticsearch index and try to do a percentile or quantile aggregation (which works great on **numeric** fields) on that field.

Assuming there are 10,000 names or cities in the string field, the expected result should be something like this:

When asking for four buckets:

```
A-E (2500), F-K (2500), L-M (2500), N-Z (2500)
```

The terms are not evenly distributed alphabetically, but the buckets should have roughly the same size. A term count of 2600,2400,2800,2200 is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite get your question. But it appears that you can do everything if you have the count of cities. So here is what you can do. Considering your documents are like so:

```
{
    "city": "New York",
    ...
}
```

You can run the following aggregation query:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/aggs/cities/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "aggs": {
        "cities_by_first_char": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "city",
                "script": "_value[0]"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this you will get occurrences of cities' first character and then you can create as many groups of ranges as you want, and then perform your calculations on the basis of that.

If you are planning to run this kind of query/aggs a lot, then I would recommend not using `script` aggs. The problem with that is it becomes very slow with a large number of docs as Elasticsearch was not made to execute scripts. If your use-case is limited to cities starting with first character only, then I will suggest that you add another field like in your doc like so:

```
{
    "city": "New York",
    "city_first_char": "N",
    ...
}
```

And now you can do a term aggregation on `city_first_char` field which will be very fast as compared to `script` aggs.

Hope this helps.